# datatool: separate data by class

Tags: tables, datatool

I'm trying to classify laws by level (federal, state and local) and by theme (waste, sanitary sewage) and show it on a table. I wrote the follow MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{legis.csv}
level;theme;norm;number;date;subject
federal;waste;"Federal Law";12305;8/2/2010;"Institutes the National Policy on Solid Waste."
state;waste;"State Law";11107;4/6/2005;"Provides general rules for management of solid waste."
local;waste;"Local Law";7797;7/10/2017;"Creates the Green Environment Fund and makes other arrangements."
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[keys={level,theme,norm,number,date,subject}]{legis}{legis.csv}

\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1cm}}l}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Federal law}\\

\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\level}{federal}\and\DTLiseq{\theme}{waste}]{legis}
{\norm=norm,\number=number,\date=date,\subject=subject}
{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\norm & \number & \date
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}@{\hspace{1cm}}{p{10cm}}
\subject
\end{tabular}\\
}

\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries State law}\\

\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\level}{state}\and\DTLiseq{\theme}{waste}]{leg}
{\norm=norm,\number=number,\date=date,\subject=subject}
{
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\norm & \number & \date
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}@{\hspace{1cm}}{p{10cm}}
\subject
\end{tabular}\\
}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Local law}\\

\DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\level}{local}\and\DTLiseq{\theme}{waste}]{leg}
{\norm=norm,\number=number,\date=date,\subject=subject}
{
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\norm & \number & \date
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}@{\hspace{1cm}}{p{10cm}}
\subject
\end{tabular}\\
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

but the log file always show the error: "Undefined control sequence.}"
what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an updated version of your database table construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{legis.csv}
level;theme;norm;number;date;subject
federal;waste;"Federal Law";12305;8/2/2010;"Institutes the National Policy on Solid Waste."
state;waste;"State Law";11107;4/6/2005;"Provides general rules for management of solid waste."
local;waste;"Local Law";7797;7/10/2017;"Creates the Green Environment Fund and makes other arrangements."
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb[keys={level,theme,norm,number,date,subject}]{legis}{legis.csv}

\begin{tabular}{ @{\hspace{1cm}} l }
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Federal law} \\
  \DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Level}{federal}\and\DTLiseq{\Theme}{waste}]{legis}
    {\Level=level,\Theme=theme,\Norm=norm,\Number=number,\Date=date,\Subject=subject}
    {%
      \begin{tabular}{ l l l }
        \Norm & \Number & \Date
      \end{tabular} \\
      \begin{tabular}{ @{\hspace{1cm}} p{10cm} }
        \Subject
      \end{tabular} \\
    } \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries State law} \\
  \DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Level}{state}\and\DTLiseq{\Theme}{waste}]{legis}
    {\Level=level,\Theme=theme,\Norm=norm,\Number=number,\Date=date,\Subject=subject}
    {%
      \begin{tabular}{ l l l }
        \Norm & \Number & \Date
      \end{tabular} \\
      \begin{tabular}{ @{\hspace{1cm}} p{10cm} }
        \Subject
      \end{tabular} \\
    } \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Local law} \\
  \DTLforeach*[\DTLiseq{\Level}{local}\and\DTLiseq{\Theme}{waste}]{legis}
    {\Level=level,\Theme=theme,\Norm=norm,\Number=number,\Date=date,\Subject=subject}
    {%
      \begin{tabular}{ l l l }
        \Norm & \Number & \Date
      \end{tabular} \\
      \begin{tabular}{ @{\hspace{1cm}} p{10cm} }
        \Subject
      \end{tabular} \\
    }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Some things that were problematic:

- Using `\number` as a definition usage for the `number` field. Instead, use something like `\Number` (or otherwise), since `\number` is a TeX primitive. Similarly, `\date` is also a macro with a different use.
- Your internal (inside `\DLTforeach`) `tabular` doesn't have the correct usage:

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{<col spec>}
  ```

  You have

  ```
  \begin{tabular}@{\hspace{1cm}}{p{10cm}}
  ```

  but it should be

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{ @{\hspace{1cm}} p{10cm} }
  ```
- Added a closing `\\` after each `\DTLforeach` and a vertical correction (`[-\normalbaselineskip]`).
- Since the conditioning within the `\DTLforeach` uses `\Level` and `\Theme`, define them as well.